# Using internationalization with phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, internationalization

I'm using jquery.18n but after phonegap build, and install the application on my device the translation does not work...

Testing with Google Chrome is normal, the problem being after passing it to the phonegap.

It is necessary to make any change in AndroidManifest or Config.xml?

Example my code in using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   jQuery.i18n.properties({
        name:'Messages', 
        path:'language/', 
        mode:'both',  
        language: 'pt-BR', 
        callback: function() {
            $("#user").attr('placeholder',Placeholder_User);
            $("#pass").attr('placeholder',Placeholder_Pass);
            $("#btn-acess").html(Button_Login);
            $("#txt-or").html(Txt_Or);
            $("#btn-register").html(Button_Register);
        }
    });   
});
```

Like said above code is working only on desktop browser on mobile phone does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try specifying language by setting locale in android. you can use following code in android. 
`Locale locale2 = new Locale("give_ur_locale_here"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale2);`
and then use blow line to lode ur html files
`super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(),2100);`